# twitter typeahead.js and access to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest twitter typeahead.js.  I would like to access the data-url property within the remote option....like the following...

I should be able to reference the url property via $('#txt2').data('url') however I would like to have a generic type ahead js function.  I am guessing $(this) doesn't have the same context as the valueKey usage.

Any ideas how I can reference the element that is using type ahead within the remote option?

```
<input type="text" id="txt2" data-name="Locations" data-url='Employee/Locations' data-valueKey="Description" />

        $('#txt2').typeahead({
        name: $(this).data('name'),
        minLength: 2,
        valueKey: $(this).data('valueKey'),
        remote: {
            url: '',
            replace: function () {
                alert(self.data('valueKey'));
                var u = $(this).data('url') + '?q=%QUERY';
                alert(u);
                return u;                    
            },
            filter: function (parsedResponse) {         //parsedResponse is the array returned from your backend                    
                return parsedResponse;
            }
        },
        template: [
            '<p class="name">{{Description}}</p>'
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan  // download and include http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/               
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        alert(datum.Code);
    });
```